# How to make an AngularJS service that will retrieve data from Behance API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to create a AngularJS service that will get data from behance profiles.

I am injecting the $http and $q services to enable me to make requests to Behance API. 
I am using a literal string for the url parameter for now to see how to resolve my issue. I will refactor my code to make it dynamic later.

*behance.js* File with the service relative to my Angular app.

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('angularPortfolioApp')
  .factory('behanceUserData', ['$q', '$http',
    function($q, $http) {
      var service = {
        getUser: function(username) { //ignore the parameter in this function I plan on implementing that after I have my question resolved.
          var d = $q.defer();
          $http({
            method: 'JSONP',
            url: 'https://www.behance.net/v2/users/USERNAME?api_key=XXX' 
          }).success(function(data) {
              d.resolve(data);
          }).error(function(reason) {
              d.reject(reason);
          });
          return d.promise;
        }
      };
      return service;
    }
]);
```

*app.js* Declaring my Angular app with it's required dependencies.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('angularPortfolioApp', ['ngResource']);
```

In Chrome dev tools console I get an error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

After doing some research I did find an article that stated that Angular does tack on a ":1" to the end of a JSONP request.

I am still having trouble understanding how I can get a successful request from an API especially from the behance API. I can still see the results in the web dev tools but since what ever I put into my .success block never runs I would appreciate some guidance.

The same code can also be seen in this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/RZ42Y38BwKZBF2pGZJSR

Comment: I don't see any errors in your plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the data into my model by using the following factory.

```
.factory('behanceUserData', ['$q', '$http', 'BEHANCE_CLIENT_ID',
   function($q, $http, BEHANCE_CLIENT_ID) {
     return {
            getUser: function(username) {
                var q = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    method: 'jsonp',
                    url: 'http://www.behance.net/v2/users/' + username,
                    params: {
                      client_id: BEHANCE_CLIENT_ID,
                      callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
                    } 
                }).success(function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  q.resolve(data);
                });
                return q.promise;
            }
        }; 

    } 
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QjKGAZ8Je4ucmhbYFIGS?p=preview).

You can use for getting any data from Behance API the following code:

```
angular.module('angularPortfolioApp', ['ngResource']);

angular
    .module('angularPortfolioApp')
    .factory('behanceUserData', ['$q', '$http',
        function($q, $http) {
            var service = {
                getUser: function(username) {
                    var d = $q.defer();
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: 'https://www.behance.net/v2/users/USERNAME?api_key=XXX' 
                    }).success(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        d.resolve(data);
                    }).error(function(reason) {
                        console.log(reason);
                        d.reject(reason);
                    });
                    return d.promise;
                }
            };
            return service;

        }
    ])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope, behanceUserData){
         $scope.getUser = function(){
            $scope.user = behanceUserData.getUser();
         }
      }
    );
```

And in your view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <button ng-click="getUser()">Get</button>
  <br/>
  {{user | json}}
</div>
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QjKGAZ8Je4ucmhbYFIGS?p=preview)

But you should change this URL: `'https://www.behance.net/v2/users/USERNAME?api_key=XXX'` because currently it not works.

Comment: Thank you Artyom for the response. I tried the changes you suggested in both plunker and in my local environment but they don't work. This is with me changing the username and api key to the appropriate values. I have checked that I am using the correct URL. What is being returned is an undefined value. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @gioducci1 I've updated answer and plunker. Please see my update. I've changed method type from 'JSONP' to 'GET'. This should work, if you get correct URL.

Comment: It was not a success. With GET methods I get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is not present on the requested resource. The response had HTTP status code of 403." The error block printed out the value of "null" to the console. Behance does have a [javascript helper library](https://github.com/behance/be.js) maybe I will need to incorporate it in order to use HTTP requests with their particular API.  Although I would like to make this a slim as possible and learn to do it right the first time.